# Изменить значение переменной GameViewController извне (SpriteKit Swift)

Tags: swift, spritekit

Речь пойдёт и Swift 2 и SpriteKit.
В классе GameViewController я создал UIScrollView, в котором слайдами являются сцены (SKScene). То есть когда пользователь открывает игру, перед ним ScrollView с перематывающими сценами.
В одной из этих сцен есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую слайдер должен перестать крутиться, как бы мы не водили пальцем (свойство scrollView.scrollEnabled = false).
Как мне это реализовать?

Подробнее поясню проблему: в главном классе GameViewController есть переменная под названием ScrollView (типа UIScrollView). В совсем другом классе мы понимаем что кнопка нажата и надо изменить свойство у переменной ScrollView.

Comment: я бы сказал очень странно, что контроллер не знает, что происходит с его вью.варианты как обычно: Notification, Singleton

Comment: И всё-таки я не понял как мне решить проблему.

Comment: чтобы решить проблему, вам надо переписать приложение, используя MVC. чтобы обойти проблему можете, например, использовать NSNotificationCenter, чтобы отправить нотификейшн из своего вью в контроллер.